# Excel VBA selecting multiple dynamic ranges

Tags: excel, vba, dynamic, range, union

I'm trying to selecting multiple dynamic range. Trying to use the union method and I'm getting Method 'Range' of 'object' Global Failed error on first Set line.

```
Dim LR As Long
LR = Range("A60000").End(xlUp).Row

Dim R1, R2, R3, R4, R5, MultiRange As Range
Set R1 = Range("A7,:A" & LR)
Set R2 = Range("D7,:D" & LR)
Set R3 = Range("G7,:G" & LR)
Set R4 = Range("H7,:H" & LR)
Set R5 = Range("J7,:J" & LR)
Set MultiRange = Union(R1, R2, R3, R4, R5)
MultiRange.Select
Selection.Copy
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem occurs because of the comma in you range statements. I.e. when you set `R1` you should write:

```
Set R1 = Range("A7:A" & LR)
```

Also, when you define the object type of your variables `R1`, ..., `R5` you should write it as

```
Dim R1 As Range, R2 As Range, R3 As Range, R4 As Range, R5 As Range, MultiRange As Range
```

Otherwise `R1`, ..., `R5` will be defined as a Variant. This doesn't cause a problem, but it will save memory and makes for a cleaner code.

Comment: plus one for the proper way of declaring variables.

Answer (score 5):

You can also set it like this:

```
Set R1 = Range("A7","A" & LR)
```

What you did is you kinda mixed up the Range syntax.
See below some common Range Syntax:

**Using `:` to define `Range`:**

```
Range("A1:A" & LR) '~~> where LR holds the last row number
```

**Using `,` to define `Range`:**

```
Range("A1","A" & LR)
```

**Using `Cells` property:**

```
Range(Cells(1, "A"),Cells(LR, "A"))
Range(Cells(1, 1),Cells(LR, 1)) '~~> another way
```

**Using `Range` property:**

```
Range(Range("A1"),Range("A" & LR))
Range(Range("A1").address & ":" & Range("A" & LR).Address) '~~> yet another complicated way
```

All syntax above evaluates to: `$A$1:$A$(LR)`
Each have certain advantages and uses.
Use the syntax you're most comfortable with.

**Additional:**

This one uses `Intersect Function`:

```
Set R1 = Intersect(Columns("A:A"),Rows("1:" & LR))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue with your code is that you put comma "," after A7, D7, .....
"Set R1 = Range("A7,:A" & LR)"
Try this code:

```
Sub JubaTest()

Dim LR As Long
Dim R1, R2, R3, R4, R5, MultiRange As Range

LR = Range("A60000").End(xlUp).Row

Set R1 = Range("A7:A" & LR)
Set R2 = Range("D7:D" & LR)
Set R3 = Range("G7:G" & LR)
Set R4 = Range("H7:H" & LR)
Set R5 = Range("J7:J" & LR)
Set MultiRange = Union(R1, R2, R3, R4, R5)
MultiRange.Select

End Sub
```

Comment: Think the main issue has been answered already in the accepted post which you should read carefully as you are repeating the initial declaration error `Dim R1, R2, .. As Range` instead of `Dim R1 As Range, R2 As Range, R3 As Range, ...` @AhmedBerkane