# VBA How to delete in a specific direcitons?

Tags: vba, excel

I want to delete all values starting from `A2:O2` and `LOWER` , i.e. `A3:O3`, `A4:O4`, `A5:O5`

```
  A    B    C     ....         O        P    Q
1 ..............................
2 deletedeletedeletedeletedelete
3 deletedeletedeletedeletedelete 
4 deletedeletedeletedeletedelete
5 deletedeletedeletedeletedelete
```

I am not sure how to do this

```
Sub DeleteLower()   
    Range("A2:O1048576").Select
    Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, 23).Select
    Selection.ClearContents
end sub
```

How do I explain that I need the range of `"A2:0 infinity "` `"A2:O1048576"`  ?

Comment: see [HERE](http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s9/win005.htm) to find your last row. Also, see [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/71180/how-can-i-find-last-row-that-contains-data-in-the-excel-sheet-with-a-macro) which will lead you to various links on answers posted in SO regarding the same topic. Then see [EXAMPLE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21616455/excel-vba-selecting-multiple-dynamic-ranges/21618018#21618018) for various ways on how you can use your `last row(LR)` to get your dynamic range.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something like this would work for you:

```
Sub RemoveValues()
    ActiveSheet.Range(ActiveSheet.Range("A2:O2").Address, ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).Address).ClearContents
End Sub
```

This will remove all content from cells `A2:O2` and downward.