# Using "cells" with "range"

Tags: vba, excel

I have been searching for this for a while now and I have not been successful.

I am trying to use range with cells command in VBA, and the last row is variable. Moreover, I am not getting consecutive columns.

I have to select range `S2:S9` and `U2:U9` (as already said, last row can be variable). I know this command works:

```
Range(Cells(2, 19), Cells(NumberofRows, 19)).select
```

But I need to select 2 different columns that are not consecutive. I am trying something like this but no success:

```
Range(Cells(2, 19), Cells(NumLinhas, 19);(Cells(2, 21), Cells(NumLinhas, 21)).Select
```

Does anyone know how to do it?

Answer (score 8):

Another option is to use the [`Union()` Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa213609(v=office.11).aspx) within VBA.

```
Union(Range(Cells(2, 19), Cells(NumLinhas, 19)), _
    Range(Cells(2, 21), Cells(NumLinhas, 21))).Select
```

If you have more ranges you wish to add to the union, you can continue to add ranges to the union like below. This is particularly useful when you incorporate a loop into adding ranges to the union.

```
Dim rngUnion As Range

Set rngUnion = Union(Range("D1:D2"), Range("H1:H2"))
Set rngUnion = Union(rngUnion, Range("B1:B2"))
Set rngUnion = Union(rngUnion, Range("F1:F2"))
rngUnion.Select
```

Answer (score 7):

You could just use this:

```
Range("S2:S" & intLastRow & ",U2:U" & intLastRow).Select
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stick with your logic using `Range` and `Cells` try this:

```
Range(Range(Cells(2, 19), Cells(NumLinhas, 19)).Address & "," & _
      Range(Cells(2, 21), Cells(NumLinhas, 21)).Address).Select
```

A bit long but you'll make your logic work.
You can also check the following links:

- [Using Cells](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20487279/2685412)
- [Dynamic Ranges](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21618018/2685412)
- [Avoiding Select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros)